# Why is RockMongo not showing my databases?

Tags: mongodb, rockmongo

[image]

I followed all the instructions for installing mongodb and RockMongo from here:
http://www.hackthesec.co.in/2016/05/how-to-install-mongodb-with-rockmongo.html

Instead of showing the RockMongo login/password screen, I am just getting a display of the files inside of my /var/www/html/rockmongo folder. I added a test database in my mongoshell but it's not being displayed and also from what I googled I don't think RockMongo is supposed to look like this. I am not sure what I am missing. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: As at March 2018, RockMongo was last updated in Sept 2015 and predates all current production releases of MongoDB. Even if you get it set up, there will be compatibility issues. I would strongly recommend looking into an actively maintained tool. One example would be [MongoDB Compass](https://www.mongodb.com/download-center#compass) ; Compass Community Edition is included as part of the MongoDB 3.6 server installation process.

Comment: thanks, didn't know it worked with centos!